# Hadoop. Problems trying to initialise HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am new to Hadoop and trying to configure it on my machine. When trying to initialise the hdfs with the command

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

I get the message

```
Format aborted in /data/nn
```

Before the namenode shuts down.

What am i missing from the configuration?

can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: If someone is going to downvote me can you at least tell me why? This way I can know where i have gone wrong. I dont have a stack trace or any additional information so my question will be a bit terse. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Its important you use uppercase Y when prompted to format the namenode.